# div rel click function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting trouble to make a click function for multiple divs which have same `rel` value.

JavaScript:

```
$("[rel=begenici]").click(function () {
    var postu = $(this).attr(id);
    alert(postu);
});
```

HTML:

```
<div rel='begenici' id='2654'></div>
```

Where am I doing a mistake?

Comment: Use this `'id'` instead of `id` .

Comment: and use `$("[rel='begenici']")` instead of `$("[rel=begenici]")`

Comment: @Freezystem In this case that is not _compulsory_, but better to use quotes. This'll also work without quotes, but when the attribute value contains space, then quotes **must** be used.

Comment: IMO, you should always prefer the safe way unless you really know what you're doing. Web languages are highly permissive, so your code have to be strict. @Tushar : I have no doubt on your web skills but, I can't presume of the asker ones.

Comment: @Freezystem You're right, that's why I've added quotes in the answer :)

Comment: @Freezystem What's with the skills of the question asker ?, Thats offensive and off topic.

Comment: @user198989 Excuse me but "skills" may not be the proper word. I was thinking of language knowlegde. Sorry if I offend you.

Comment: Gotcha, no porblems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the attribute name in quotes

```
var postu = $(this).attr('id');
```

**Complete Code:**

```
$("[rel='begenici']").click(function () {
    var postu = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(postu);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed the single quotes

```
$("[rel='begenici']").click(function () {
    var postu = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(postu);
});
```

And not just one the first line (Thanks Tushar :))